# What happened to this guy? (Graphic)

Tags: infection, wound, necrosis-dead-skin

There's an image floating round the internet.

[image: A row of infected wounds]

The source, near as I can tell, is an upload to Pinterest with no explanation.

If there were just one wound you might think it was a spider bite, but there are several all in a row. And they're all tied off as if the cavities are all connected underneath the skin.

What is going on here? What happened to this guy?

Comment: Those are obviously some deep puncture wounds but there's no way to know what made them. Machinery, a large wild animal, or knife attack all come to mind. That's not a spider bite, and besides, [spiders do not bite](https://arthropodecology.com/2012/02/15/spiders-do-not-bite/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT a spider bite even if it was just one deep cut. Spider bites are rare and more than 99% of spider bite cases are usually some person's overactive imagination. Doctors get rather tired hearing these stories and roll their eyes when they hear them.

Whatever happened to the man, it must've become infected. The rubber (or silicone) tubing is meant to keep the wounds open to allow for drainage. It could easily have come about from something that Carey mentioned and was contaminated.